# TrackBy from parent to child component

Tags: angular, parent-child, ngfor

I havent been able to find an answer to this.

I have a parent and child component, and my child has an ngFor with a trackBy function for the index. I tried emitting the data just like any other function from a parent to a child with `@Output` but i couldnt get it working.

any ideas?

child html

```
     *ngFor="let server of (dnsServers$ | async)?.dns;
     let index = index trackBy: trackByIndex.emit(index)"
```

child ts

```
@Output() trackByIndex: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

parent html

```
(trackByIndex)="trackByIndex($event)"
```

parent ts

```
trackByIndex(index) {
        return index
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? :)

Comment: I'm trying to use trackby with the smart dumb component architecture, as apposed to using trackby in the dumb component alone with it's own html template

Comment: Did you managed to find any solution to this one?